# wordpress: Username referral in url

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I am using wordpress and I am trying to pass the usename var from www.mysite.com/username to a var in a wordpress page. I have multiple issue. I have no idea if the rewrite is not working and the wordpress pages comment out my php. Any suggestions? Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /index.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass the vars of www.mysite.com/username to a var in a WordPress page, because that will mean that all the links will lead to the same page and the var as to the username, you will get a lot of conflicts and a lot of problems.

I can share you my code on creating a profile page. EG: Profile and having pretty permalink like
www.mysite.com/profile/eek

That will acces the Wordpress page Profile, that I have set as page-profile.php in my theme, and the next variable (eg: Eek) into a variable, in my example it will be a $who variable.

Add this to the functions.php

```
add_filter( 'page_rewrite_rules', 'profile_page_rewrite_rules' );
function profile_page_rewrite_rules( $rewrite_rules )
{
    end( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_pattern = key( $rewrite_rules );
    $last_replacement = array_pop( $rewrite_rules );
    $rewrite_rules +=  array(
        '(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&who=$matches[2]',
        $last_pattern => $last_replacement,
    );
    return $rewrite_rules;
}

add_rewrite_tag('%who%','([^&]+)');
```

Then update the permalinks from Settings->Permalinks Settings -> Save.

And in the page-profile.php

To get the current user, I have this snippet:

```
<?php  $who = (get_query_var('who')) ? get_query_var('who') : 0; 
        if($who){$user = get_user_by('login', $who);}

        else{
            if( is_user_logged_in() ){
                $user = wp_get_current_user();
            }else{$user = 0;}
        }
?>
```

More details on adding a rewrite rule to WordPress here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Also, I am using a cool plugin to debug my rewrites, it's this one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/ (yes, it's 2 years old, but it still works like a charm).

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

if i've understand the problem, you was going in wrong way ... so maybe actually you'll follow this way instead (in case anybody on 2018 will still fall into this answer)

```
http://mywordpress/?u=myusername
```

but could be also:

```
https://www.axew3.com/w3/dropbox/?u=axew3
```

check the passed var with just:

```
$_GET['u'];
```

but maybe i've misunderstand the question ...